# How to make days into tags?

Tags: ruby, arrays, join, days

How can we embed `<span class="label label-primary">` into the below array so that each day of the week that is generated from the ruby is its own tag? We would take the comma out.

`<%= challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join(', ') %>`

As an example I tried:

`<%= challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join('<span class="label label-primary"></span>') %>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
<% challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %>
  <span class="label label-primary"><%= title %></span>
<% end %>
```

or with `content_tag`:

```
<% challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %>
  <%= content_tag(:span, title, class: "label label-primary")
<% end %>
```

You could try tackling the problem this way as well (this one is "less ERB-ish" thou):

```
<%= challenged.committed
              .map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }
              .map { |title| content_tag(:span, title, class: "label label-primary") }
              .join(', ')
              .html_safe %>
```

Don't forget to call `html_safe` on generated string, as all the HTML entities will be encoded and you will see "plain" HTML, rather the nicely formatted one.

Hope this helps!

Good Luck!